# Grails: What is the difference between using actionName and pageScope.actionName inside taglibs?

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, gsp, taglib, grails-controller

In my company's codebase I'm seeing `pageScope.actionName` being used. Is it safe to drop`pageScope`?

Update:

I am interested in knowing whether actionName is a late addition to the framework that makes `pageScope.actionName` obsolete.

Update 2:

Here is how it is used in one taglib:

```
def url = "/${pageScope.controllerName}/${attrs.action}"
```

Comment: Without further context it's difficult to say definitively, but in general, yes it's safe.

Comment: @JoshuaMoore any good reason this question was downvoted? Am I missing something?

Comment: I didn't downvote it, but it may be because it's a very general question with no specifics as to why you are concerned, why you are looking to do what you are doing, etc. I don't know why it got downvoted, just guessing.

Comment: grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tag%20Libraries/…. didn't downvote you either maybe someone thought if you are not using it and its working for you why the question.
. I will + itto neutral. As for the usage in your company code, I guess it depends on how long ago it was written. Referring to docs in 2010 like:
http://www.dzone.com/links/grails_pagescope_variable_in_gsps_and_taglibraries.html and  http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/overriding-plugin-templates-in-grails-application there are a few more around people were using it  then, can't comment on if it was essential back then.

Comment: Thanks @vahid for your detailed explanation. You could make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pageScope](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Tag%20Libraries/pageScope.html). As for the usage in your company code, I guess it depends on how long ago it was written. Referring to docs in 2010 like: [grails_pagescope_variable_in_gsps_and_taglibraries](http://www.dzone.com/links/grails_pagescope_variable_in_gsps_and_taglibraries.html) and [overriding-plugin-templates-in-grails-application](http://artur.ejsmont.org/blog/content/overriding-plugin-templates-in-grails-application) there are a few more around people were using it then, can't comment on if it was essential back then.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further context it's difficult to say definitively, but in general, yes it's safe.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith @Josua, What I was interested in was whether `actionName` is a late addition to the framework that makes `pageScope.actionName` obsolete.